# Move and align objects to connect them

Tags: mesh

Is there a way to move an object on the same UV map to connect to another object like vertex to vertex on Blender? Snapping only moves 1 vertex and won't align my object perfectly. I'm trying to fit a fan blade into the hole. Snapping aligns one vertex but when I try to do the others it moves the one I aligned.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *> Cursor To Selected* followed by right click <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Set Origin > Set Origin to 3D Cursor* and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *> Selection to Cursor*. Then join the 2 meshes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and merge vertices with <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge By Distance*.

[image]